# resize bootsrap modal on android device doesn't work on my galaxy

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I want to resize the modal window on my android device.
It contains a table that is not visualized in a complite mode.
I've tried with this function but it doesn't go...

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
$(this).find('.modal-dialog').css({width:'auto',
                           height:'auto', 
                          'max-height':'100%'});
```

});

on the emulator modal window is visualized in the corrct mode...

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=modal

Comment: what is the version of your android?

Comment: in the samsung I use there's android 4.4.4

Answer (score 0):

I've solved with this code:

```
var h = window.innerHeight;
            h *= 0.7;
            document.getElementById('modal').style.height = h + "px";
            document.getElementById('myModalBody').style.height = h - 50 + "px";
```